# Scrapy crawler extract urls but miss half callbacks

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm facing a strange issue while trying to scrape this [URL](http://www.ikea.com/fr/fr/catalog/productsaz/8/):

To perform the crawling, I designed this:

```
class IkeaSpider(CrawlSpider) :

    name = "Ikea"
    allower_domains = ["http://www.ikea.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ikea.com/fr/fr/catalog/productsaz/8/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*/catalog/products/\d+']),
            callback='parse_page',
            follow=True),
            )

    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.ERROR)

        def parse_page(self, response):

            for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="rightContent"]'):

                 Blah blah blah
```

I launch the spider from the command-line, and I can see urls normally scraped, but, for some of them, the callback doesn't work (about half of them are normally scrapped).

As there is more than 150 links on this page, it may explain why the crawler is missing callbacks (too many jobs). Does some of you have any idea regarding this?

This is the log :

2015-12-25 09:02:55 [scrapy] INFO: Stored csv feed (107 items) in: test.csv
2015-12-25 09:02:55 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
 'downloader/request_bytes': 68554,
 'downloader/request_count': 217,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 217,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4577452,
 'downloader/response_count': 217,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 216,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 107,
 'file_count': 106,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 106,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 8, 2, 55, 548350),
 'item_scraped_count': 107,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 433,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 217,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 110,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 110,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 110,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 110,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 8, 2, 28, 656959)
2015-12-25 09:02:55 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished

Comment: set the log level to DEBUG and share the logs

Answer (score 0):

I've read a lot of things regarding my problem, and, apparently, the `CrawlSpider` class is not specific enough. It might explain why it misses some links, for some reasons I can't explain.
Basically, it is advised to use the `BaseSpider` class with `start_requests` and `make_requests_from_url` method to do the job in a more specific way. 
I am still not completely sure on how to do it precisely. that was just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of these auto spider classes. I usually just build exactly what I need.

```
import scrapy

class IkeaSpider(scrapy.Spider) :

    name = "Ikea"
    allower_domains = ["http://www.ikea.com/"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.ikea.com/fr/fr/cat/produits-products/"]

    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.ERROR)

        def parse(self, response):
            # You could also use a.vn-nav__link::attr(href) selector.
            for link in response.css('a:contains("/fr/cat/")::attr(href)').getall()
                yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_category)

        def parse_category(self, response):
            # parse items or potential sub categories
```